# How to insert an image in a DIV keeping the aspect ratio of the tags?

Tags: css

I made this code:

```
<div id="divImage" style="background-color: skyblue;height: 200px;">
        <div style="background-color: red;width: 8%;height: 60px;margin-left: 20px; position: relative;top:50%;margin-right: auto;transform: translateY(-50%);"></div>
        <div style="background-color: red;width: 8%;height: 60px;margin-right: 20px; position: relative;top:50%;margin-left: auto;transform: translateY(-150%);"></div>
    </div>
```

I need to insert an image in the `divImage` with a width of 100%. For this, it is necessary that the `divImage` height is not fixed (`height: 200px;`). My intention is to make this `divImage` adapt to any screen size (in%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you will need to adjust the ratio on a per image basis and when the page resizes.

```
let ratio = 1.4;
const width = containerWidth.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const imageHeight = `${width * ratio}px`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force your box to keep an aspect ratio using its pseudo elements. Here the before element will always have a certain padding top which makes the box take up its height in relation to its width because the `100%` in the equation always refers to the container's width.

```css
.divImage {
    &:before {

      // Change this line to adjust the aspect ratio
      // 1px / 1px will for example give you a square box. 
      // The first value refers to the height-part
      padding-top: 5px / 10px * 100%; 

      content: "";
      width: 1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      float: left;
      height: 0;
    }
    &:after { /* to clear float */
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
}
```

If you want to use an image in the div that covers the box add also this:

```css
.divImage {
   position: relative;
   img {
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;//might not be necessary, just check if it works without 
      height: 100%;//might not be necessary, just check if it works without 
      object-fit:cover; //or contain if you dont want it to fill the container
   }
}
```